# What are the alternatives to InfoPath

Tags: document-library, form, forms-library

I want to design form, for SharePoint library.

Previously I had deign complex InfoPath form, But now I don't want to use InfoPath form.

Since Microsoft announced in a blog post titled [Update on InfoPath and SharePoint Forms](https://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/) that InfoPath 2013 will be supported in SharePoint 2016 and within Office 365 until further notice, So what is best tools to use for form development for SharePoint.

Basically I'm looking alternative for InfoPath forms.

Please suggest some alternatives.

Comment: If you have Nintex license, then it also provides the ability to forms..

Comment: No. we don't have Nintex license.  Nintex is more expensive option.

Comment: As @Christophe points out, the MS Office blog post referenced in the question is out of date, which suggests the question needs rewriting. Remove the paragraph altogether?

Answer (score 7):

Besides the above mentioned `Infowise tools`, another example of a paid tool would be [Kintivo forms](https://www.kintivo.com/sharepoint-solutions/smart-forms-module-for-sharepoint/) and [Kwizcom forms](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx)

It allows drag-drop of fields to be displayed in the form as well as branching and conditional logic. It also has a free trial version available.

Kwizcom forms are also easy to build and create for functional/non-technical users.

Not advertising any of these above products, but was one of the developers in the team that created `Kintivo forms`.

Also, checkout this link from Sharegate which lists out various Infopath alternatives.

[5 Alternatives to InfoPath for SharePoint Forms](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/5-alternatives-to-infopath-for-sharepoint-forms)

However, if you don't want to use paid tool , you can create your own custom forms using various modern frameworks like [AngularJS forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) or [Bootstrap forms](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/) (currently in alpha, but works quite smoothly with SharePoint).

You can also create using Office Fabric UI and Angular JS integration. A great example is given here [Custom SharePoint Form Using Office UI Fabric and Angular](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/august-2016/custom-sharepoint-form-using-office-ui-fabric-and). It uses the `ngOfficeFabricUI` framework created by Andew Connell.

If you are not a big fan of any these frameworks, the using SharePoint designer, you can create your own custom forms.

[Building Custom Forms using SPD](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx)

Personally, I prefer creating custom forms using these modern frameworks as they are very simple, fast as well as provide great degree of control over the flow of data and the UI/UX experience. Also, as SharePoint provides RESTful interface to most endpoints, its easy to integrate these forms and their control their behaviour and event handling.

Answer (score 5):

Previously, I have used [Infowise tools](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/) as alternative of InfoPath form. It is very efficient. You can use it in both SharePoint Online and SharePoint on-premise. You can get free trial and free demo from them.

It gives below functionalities with Code-free toolkit:

- Forms
- Processes (advanced business logic)
- Reporting

It's very easy to use. I am not advertising it but I am just sharing my experience.

Comment: Sound's good. what are the option available there for rules, validation. Can i use html in form.

Comment: Yes. It gives much functionalities. It provides many column types for SharePoint list. You can check it on: http://www.infowisesolutions.com/

Answer (score 3):

The article is two years old, we now know that InfoPath will be supported until 2026.

Other options:

For **end users**: Excel and Word

For **Power users**:
The most recent Microsoft tool for creating forms is called PowerApps:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/
It is still quite limited, but expect frequent updates in the coming months.

For **developers**:
You could build your own custom forms using two Microsoft-supported tools: Office UI React components and the SharePoint framework.

Comment: +1 Everything seems to be pointing towards PowerApps and Flow to become the future in the forms and basic workflow space.

Answer (score 3):

I've also heard about Emgage and Plumsail. And there's the more costly Nintex solution of course. By the way, this question is a good candidate for Community Wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try SPARK Forms builder @ http://www.itlaq.com/ITLAQ_Pages/Pages/Spark.aspx

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon here; they encourage spam and drive-by answerers. Please explain what this "SPARK Forms builder" is and how it works by editing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for an alternative way to create forms in the SharePoint browser, others have already suggested a few of the many alternatives. I might add Stratus Forms to that list, though I don't have personal experience with it.

If, however, you are looking for alternatives to other InfoPath capabilities such as running outside the browser in an app, or populating your SharePoint library with editable XML files, then I suggest you investigate Formotus (my company).

Here's a good place to start: [Formotus for InfoPath Users](http://www.formotus.com/go/formotus-for-infopath-users)

Answer (score 2):

You can check this list by Mark Jones, there are many alternative including the ones already mentioned in the previous posts: http://list.ly/list/EKk-infopath-forms-alternatives

I work for PDF Share Forms, full disclosure. I suggest to give it a look: [PDF Share Forms Information Worker](http://iw.pdfshareforms.com/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=Comments%20section)

It brings a rich toolset for for design and integration with SharePoint as well as using all the good stuff from PDF format - signatures, archival, it looks the same on all devices, can work offline etc.